# The Stone-Čech compactification is the biggest compactification for Tychonov spaces

Tags: general-topology

What shown below is a reference from "Elementos de Topología General" by Fidel Cassarubias Segura and Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa

> **Definition**
>
> Let $X$ be a Tychonov space and 
>   $$
> \beta=\Delta_{f\in C(X,[0,1])}f:X\rightarrow[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}
> $$
>   the diagonal function of the collection $C(X,[0,1])$ and $\beta X$ the closure of $\beta[X]$ in $[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$. So the compactification $(\beta,\beta X)$ is named Stone-Čech compactification of $X$.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> If $X$ is a Tychonov space then any Hausdorff compactification $(h,K)$ of $X$ is such that $(h,K)\preccurlyeq(\beta,\beta X)$.
>
> *Proof*. From previous lemma we know that $K$ is embeddable in $[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$ and so without loss of generality we can suppose that $K$ is a subspace of $[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$. So we consider the function
>   $$
> H:[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}\rightarrow[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}
> $$
>   defined as
>   $$
> [H(\xi)](g):=\xi(g\circ h)
> $$
>   where $g\in C(K,[0,1])$ and $\xi\in[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$.
>
> So we observe that if $g$ is an element of $C(K,[0,1])$ and if we compose $H$ with the projection $\pi_g:[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}\rightarrow[0,1]$ we obtain the projection $\pi_{g\circ h}:[0,1]^{C(\beta X,[0,1])}\rightarrow[0,1]$, that is $\pi_g\circ H=\pi_{g\circ h}$, and so for the universal mapping theorem for products we can claim that $h$ is continuous.
>
> So we consider the continuous function $p:=H|_{\beta X}:\beta X\rightarrow[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$ and we prove that $p\circ\beta=h$. So we pick $x\in X$ and $g\in C(K,[0,1])$ and we observe that
>   $$
> [(p\circ\beta)(x)](g)=[p(\beta(x))](g)=[H(\beta(x))](g)=[\beta(x)](g\circ h)=(g\circ h)(x)=[h(x)](g)
> $$
>   and so for the arbitrariness of $g$ we can claim that $[p\circ\beta](x)=h(x)$ for any $x\in X$, that is $p\circ\beta=h$. Then finally we observe that $p[\beta X]=K$ and so we can claim that $(h,K)\preccurlyeq(\beta,\beta X)$.

Here for the sake of completeness the original text of the proof: I hope that I made a good translation.

[image]

Well I don't understand why $p[\beta X]=K$ and why $(g\circ h)(x)=h(x)(g)$. Then in addition I don't understand why  the domain of $\pi_{g\circ h}$ is $[0,1]^{C(\beta X,[0,1])}$ rather than $[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$, but this seems to be irrelevant for the proof.

So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p \circ \beta = h$ tells you also that $p[\beta[X]] = h[X]$ and $h[X]$ is dense in $K$ (from $(h,K)$ being a compactification). So $p[\beta X]$ is a compact (hence closed in the Hausdorff $K$!) subset of $K$ that contains the dense set $h[X]$ and so must equal $\overline{h[X]}=K$.

Note the subtlety in the proof of $p \circ \beta=h$, where we identify a point of $K$ by its "vector of values" in $[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$, and that's why we work with the values at all $g \in C(K, [0,1])$.

Indeed in this context $\pi_{g \circ h}$ has domain $[0,1]^{C(X, [0,1])}$ as this is the domain on which $H$ is defined, and fits with the given diagram.

It's probably just a typo, but it "happens" that $C(X,[0,1]$ "sort of equals" $C(\beta X,[0,1])$ anyway (every $f$ defined on $X$ has a natural "extension" $\beta f$ defined on $\beta X$ (namely $\pi_f \restriction_{\beta[X]}$) and we can "restrict" any continuous map $g$ from $\beta X$ to $[0,1]$ by $g \circ \beta: X \to [0,1]$ and these operations are each other's inverses. So we have a antural isomorphism between $C(X,[0,1])$ and $C(\beta X, [0,1])$, which will in fact turn out to characterise $\beta X$ among all compactifications of $X$.

Comment: Perhaps I understood. We know that $\beta X$ is compact and so $p[\beta X]$ is too compact, since $p$ is continuous; moreover $[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$ is hausdorff and contains $p[\beta X]$ and so this is closed. Then $\beta[X]\subseteq\overline{\beta[X]}:=\beta X$ and so $p[\beta[X]]=h[X]$ is contained in $p[\beta X]$, that is closed, and so $K=\overline{h[X]}\subseteq p[\beta X]\equiv p[\overline{\beta[X]}]\subseteq\overline{p[\beta[X]]}=\overline{h[X]}=K$, that is $p[\beta X]=K$. Is it right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $p \circ \beta = h$ so $p[\beta X]$ contains $h[X]$. $p[\beta X]$ is compact, because $\beta X$ is and $p$ is continuous.

Comment: Sorry, but rereading the proof I don't understand why $(p\circ h)(x)=h(x)(g)$, since $(p\circ h)(x)=g(h(x))$. Anyway  $h(x)$ is a function of the product $[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$. Could you help me, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro this is because we identify $K$ with a subset of that power.

Comment: Okay, but more exatly why the value in $x$ of the function $g\circ h$ is equal to the value in $g$ of the function $h(x)$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $p$ is the restriction of $\beta$ and that’s how $\beta$ is defined.

Comment: So I know that there is an embedding $\phi$ of $K$ in $[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$ and so I can claim that $h(x)$ is a function of $[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$. Now I must prove that for any function $g\in [0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$ it results that $g(h(x))=[h(x)](g)$. Could you prove it, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes sorry I meant $H$ instead of $\beta$. Your last fact is the definition of $H$!

Comment: Okay, so for any $\xi\in[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$ and $g\in C(K,[0,1])$ it results that $[H(\xi)](g)=\xi(g\circ h)$. Now we have $h(x)\in[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}$ and if for any $x\in X$ we found a $\xi_{h(x)}\in[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$ such that $h(x)=H(\xi_{h(x)}$), then it results that $[h(x)](g)=[H(\xi_{h(x)})](g)=\xi_{h(x)}(g\circ h)$. So how to prove that $\xi_{h(x)}(g\circ h)=(g\circ h)(x)$? Could you help me, please?